# Autosize ScatterChart series

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

When I create a `ScatterChart` I always have this redundant blank space on the left and bottom and I want to remove it.

[image]

Here is my piece of code. `xAxis.autosize()` and `yAxis.autosize()` don't change anything.

```
vbox {
    add(ScatterChart(NumberAxis(), NumberAxis()).apply {
        val seriesMap: HashMap<String, XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> = HashMap()

        pointsList
                .map { it.decisionClass }
                .distinct()
                .forEach {
                    seriesMap.put(it, XYChart.Series())
                }

        for (point in pointsList) {
            seriesMap.get(point.decisionClass)?.data(point.axisesValues[0], point.axisesValues[1])
        }

        seriesMap
                .toSortedMap()
                .forEach { key, value ->
                    value.name = key
                    data.add(value)
                }
        xAxis.autosize()
        yAxis.autosize()
    })
}
```

How to autosize a series?

Comment: In Java, you would call `setForceZeroInRange(false)` on each of the axes (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/NumberAxis.html#forceZeroInRangeProperty)). I don't know Kotlin, but perhaps you can do the translation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@James_D](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162425/xyz) I ended up with this piece of code.

```
vbox {
    add(ScatterChart(NumberAxis(), NumberAxis()).apply {
        val seriesMap: HashMap<String, XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> = HashMap()

        pointsList
                .map { it.decisionClass }
                .distinct()
                .forEach {
                    seriesMap.put(it, XYChart.Series())
                }

        for (point in pointsList) {
            seriesMap.get(point.decisionClass)?.data(point.axisesValues[0], point.axisesValues[1])
        }

        seriesMap
                .toSortedMap()
                .forEach { key, value ->
                    value.name = key
                    data.add(value)
                }
        (xAxis as NumberAxis).setForceZeroInRange(false)
        (yAxis as NumberAxis).setForceZeroInRange(false)
    })
}
```